# How can I add annotation in ggplotly animation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am creating animated plotly graph for my assignment in r, where I am comparing several models with various number of observations. I would like to add annotation showing what is the RMSE of the current model - this means I would like to have text that changes together with slider. Is there any easy way how to do that?

Here is my dataset stored on GitHub. There already is created variable with RMSE: [data](https://github.com/johnnyheineken/ML-for-Ectrics/blob/master/Individual%20Assignment%201/data.RData)

The base ggplot graphic is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(values_predictions, aes(x = x))  +
    geom_line(aes(y = preds_BLR, frame = n, colour = "BLR")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = preds_RLS, frame = n, colour = "RLS")) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = target, frame = n, colour = "target"), alpha = 0.3) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = sin(2 * pi * x), colour = "sin(2*pi*x)"), alpha = 0.3)  +
    ggtitle("Comparison of performance) + 
    labs(y = "predictions and targets", colour = "colours")
```

This is converted to plotly, and I have added an animation to the Plotly graph:

```
plot <- ggplotly(p) %>%
        animation_opts(easing = "linear",redraw = FALSE)
plot
```

Thanks!

Comment: Answered your question :) I made my own data frame as your data on GitHub was said to be corrupted. Best practise would be to provide a minimal dataset within the question though as done in the answer.

Comment: I edited the data, they should be working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add annotations to a ggplot graph using the `annotate` function: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 10), y = rnorm(100, mean = 10))

# Build model
fit <- lm(x ~ y, data = df)

# function finds RMSE
RMSE <- function(error) { sqrt(mean(error^2)) }

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text",  x = Inf, y  = Inf, hjust = 1.1, vjust = 2, 
           label = paste("RMSE", RMSE(fit$residuals)) )
```

[image]

There seems to be a bit of a problem converting between ggplot and plotly. However this workaround [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/170) shows a workaround which can be used:

```
ggplotly(plot) %>%
  layout(annotations = list(x = 12, y = 13, text = paste("RMSE",
    RMSE(fit$residuals)), showarrow = F))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! I should have stated that I also encountered the annotate problem. I came to the same conclusion justa s you did. However as my plot is animated, I fit several different models and I need to update RMSE in each frame:/ this method leaves RMSE same for every frame.

Comment: Make the job of the people trying to help you easier: if you have already tried things before posting, **always** include these in the question. Otherwise, those trying to help you are going to run into the problems you faced. Also you should really state "I fit several different models and I need to update RMSE in each frame" within the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of adding data dependent text using the built in iris dataset with correlation as text to ggplotly.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydata = iris %>% rename(variable1=Sepal.Length, variable2= Sepal.Width)

shift_right = 0.1 # number from 0-1 where higher = more right
shift_down = 0.02 # number from 0-1 where higher = more down

p = ggplot(mydata, aes(variable1,variable2))+
    annotate(geom = "text",
             label = paste0("Cor = ",as.character(round(cor.test(mydata$variable1,mydata$variable2)$estimate,2))),
             x = min(mydata$variable1)+abs(shift_right*(min(mydata$variable1)-max(mydata$variable1))), 
             y =  max(mydata$variable2)-abs(shift_down*(min(mydata$variable2)-max(mydata$variable2))), size=4)+
    geom_point()

ggplotly(p) %>%  style(hoverinfo = "none", traces = 1) # remove hover on text
```

[image: ggplotly with text]